# Command in cmd works but when I try to use Python it says 'is not recognized as internal or external command'

Tags: windows, cmd, python-3.5

[running cmd with python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXMDx.jpg)

Hi, I have uploaded a picture showing my problem. Whenever I try to issue the command 'runpkr00' in cmd.exe, the program runs fine and smooth.

`runpkr00`

however, if I try to open cmd with Python and write the same code, I get the error as 'not recognized as internal or external command'

```
>>>import os
>>>os.system('cmd')
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

`C:\Python35>runpkr00`
'runpkr00' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have checked my `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`that I have `C:\Windows\System32`, `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32 .

Are there any other solutions for this?
I am running Windows 8.1 Single Language 64bit.

PS. If I try to input `ipconfig` instead of `runpkr00`, both are working.

Comment: @shawnt00 I am not really sure but I think it is more on a path problem. But I have no idea what to change. Adding `.exe` doesn't work either.

Comment: Why don't you specify the path?

Comment: Instead of running `runpkr00`, use `ECHO %PATH%` to see what is actually in the PATH variable.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have tried that too. I wrote `C:\Windows\System32\runpkr00`. But still did not work for me. Tried writing everything and restarting as well. That's why I ended up here. Just in case anyone experienced the same problem.

Comment: @Liturgist I have checked `ECHO %PATH%` and everything is still there.

Comment: Is it permissions? Can you even see that file in the directory from the Python shell?

Comment: @shawnt00 I'm not sure. Do you mind guiding me how?

Comment: @YonP - Use `DIR C:\path\to\runpkr00.bat` Is the directory containing `runpkr00.bat` in the PATH variable?

Comment: @Liturgist I used `DIR C:\path\to\runpkr.exe` in cmd and it is there. runpkr00.exe is also in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @Liturgist I just tried using `DIR` in the cmd opened with Python and it says `file not found`

Comment: Are you sure it's actually in the `system32` directory?

Comment: @YonP - When you used `DIR`, were there any files in that directory? What is the current working directory in the cmd.exe shell that Python starts? Use the `CD` command to find out?

Comment: Type `where runpkr00.*` If it's not found it's not in the path. I suspect it is in your profilefolder, and thus not in the path. Type `cd %userprofile%`.

Comment: @shawnt00 I am 100% positive that it is inside the `system32` folder. Are there any instances of Python running cmd differently than if I just run cmd on my own?

Comment: @Liturgist i used `DIR` on the cmd opened with Python and all files originally inside system32 is there. If I try to put something inside system32 and find it with cmd executed by Python, it is nowhere to be found. But If I opened cmd from windows, I can see it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bgalea after using `where runpkr00.*` it says `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` This happens when I use `where runpkr00` in the cmd opened by Python. If I just opened cmd normally in windows and used `where runpkr00.*` it returns `C:\Windows\System32\runpkr00.exe`

Comment: Do a `path` in both environments. How is cmd run by python configured?

Comment: @bgalea I'm sorry, what do you mean when you said "do a `path` in both environments"? I have written a Path variable in `USER variables` and edited the Path in `system variables`. Can you configure cmd run by Python? I just used `import os` then `os.system('cmd')` or `os.system('start')`.

Comment: Type `path` in both environments.

Comment: @bgalea I just did and they both contain the same content.

Comment: And that content is?

Comment: @bgalea the returned `path` from both environment, both contain the same variables  (e.g `C:\Windows\System32;%SYSTEMROOT%`).

Comment: Big thanks to you guys, I finally managed to make it run now. @bgalea

Comment: @shawnt00 thank you kind sir for sparing some time

Comment: @Liturgist thank you kind sir for sparing some time

Answer (score 1):

Well as I stated that my problem is that if i run cmd simply in windows, I can run the .exe file. But if I run cmd with Python, it gets lost somewhere.

What I did was to edit my `path` variables. 
I wrote down `C:\Windows\SysWOW64' inside`path`and also placed a copy of my`file.exe`inside the`C:\Windows\SysWOW64` directory. 
Fortunately enough, this got it working. Thank you for helping.